# Configuring proxing beans in Spring aop + cglib

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, cglib

We've got a Spring 3.1 web-application using spring-aop with cglib library.
spring.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

That means that a proxy will be created using cglib for every bean.

Now we need to use a db connection pool bean with com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource:

```
<bean id="connectionPool" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<!-- here are some properties -->
</bean>
```

The problem is the ComboPooledDataSource class is marked as final. And cglib can't proxy final classes.

How to mark "connectionPool" bean not to be proxied?

Comment: What are your pointcut definitions? Why Spring thinks that the data source needs to be proxied?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should use exclude patterns for which you don't need proxies.

[Please refer the link for more details:-](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html)